# Star Wars IV, V, VI "Disney Updates"

Tags: star-wars, alternate-version

If I had purchased the original Star Wars IV, V, & VI movies that came out when they were released in the late 70's and early 80's, what major differences would I see compared to the current Disney versions available today? (i.e. Disney Plus versions)

There is some information in this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changes_in_Star_Wars_re-releases) but the changes are fairly vague.

Comment: "If [you] had purchased the original Star Wars IV, V, & VI DVD's that came out when they were released in the late 70's and early 80's"... you'd be from an alternate dimension, because DVD wasn't a thing until the late 90s. In seriousness, if you're looking to identify the differences between releases, you'd be better served by doing a little preliminary research - figure out _the actual release dates_ you want to ask about.

Comment: I watched A New Hope on Laser Disc in 1992.  That option was available.

Comment: It might be tough also because even before Disney took over, Lucas had made changes with updated editions. It might be easier to ask, 'What Disney changed from the previous editions?;

Comment: Something to consider - you can get the original trilogy in their original theatrical versions on the limited edition DVDs. Very much worth it. Those of us who grew up with the originals get a sense of "nails on the chalkboard" pain when seeing and hearing the atrocities Lucas crapped into the re-releases then act like they over-rule the originals. You know you heard "Han shot first" before. Nevermind the music and entire ending of RotJ. Not a single thing he added to the originals improves them at all. They only destroy. Best to not even watch the remastered ones

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short of watching the movie cuts side by side, it would be very hard to get more specific than the wiki article does.Yet ultimately, they can be summed up as CGI and continuity changes.

George Lucas Felt like the technology at the time limited his vision for what he wanted it to look like. Lots of changes are like that. Other changes are for story. The prequels had many characters that play the younger versions of the characters in the original trilogy, so some changes are simply actors from the prequels replacing the actors in the original. (for example: the voice of Boba Fett, Anakin force ghost in ROTJ, and the hologram of the emperor.)

Here are some videos of the comparisons because, like I said, it is the best way to see all of the changes.

[New Hope changes part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNbzSH84mj0)

[New Hope changes part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvbrVFP_f0w)

[Empire Strikes Back changes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmWjPoqEhzg)

[Return of the Jedi changes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2obEPFGrMs)

[The Phantom Menace: Yoda changes, puppet to CGI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxaZxpNTm8A)

[Another list I found just now that you might like](https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/star-wars-changes/)